Gnosis Safe: Chiado v.1.3.0 - unsupported base contract
I'd like to deploy the Safe Singleton contract v1.3.0 on Mainnet and Gnosis (Sepolia and Chiado on testing), but I see a warning in SafeWalletUI when using the Chiado network.
Deployment is done via SafeSDK:
const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.init({
  isL1SafeSingleton: true,
  provider: RPC_URL,
  safeVersion: '1.3.0',
  signer: env.SAFE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE_KEY,
})

const safeContract = await safeFactory.deploySafe({
  owners: ['owner1', 'owner2', 'owner3'],
  threshold: 1,
})

Sepolia Safe: https://app.safe.global/transactions/history?safe=sep:0x25cc7d4bCA86B75937f9F6D1D26db649bDB2FF41 -> everything is correct
Chiado Safe: https://app.safe.global/transactions/history?safe=chiado:0x98E0932f6A803068052BD2d43827F49840d7B1F5 -> warning

Double check of supported networks https://docs.safe.global/advanced/smart-account-supported-networks?version=v1.3.0&search=chiado&expand=10200, and the factory and master copy contract addresses are the same.

FYI: I deployed a L2 contract on Chiado a few weeks ago and it looks ok https://app.safe.global/settings/setup?safe=chiado:0xB104d8E65e1933c226d1350C6A9fe9BBE3e5f6e2
Do you know why SafeWalletUI doesn't support the singleton contract?

When I updated the "@safe-global/protocol-kit" from "4.0.3" to "5.0.3", I got "SafeProxy contract is not deployed on the current network" error when trying to deploy the contract. The contract address prediction works though.

Thanks for the good question.
Chiado, the testnet of Gnosis, is an unfortunate special case for Safe, as the deployment of the Safe Singleton Factory failed (transaction). This has only happened once in the history of Safe.
The address of the Safe Proxy Factory in the image is different from the address on all other chains, leading to errors.
I have contacted the Wallet team about the error you encountered with the Wallet and will get back to you soon.
Unfortunately, the only answer regarding the SDK is that we don't currently support Chiado. I'm sorry about that, and I hope you find another testnet where you can experiment with Safe.

It looks like a private URL, I'm getting 404 when opening the URL... I tried to deploy Safe L1 1.3.0 on Sepolia, and I'm getting the same error "SafeProxy contract is not deployed on the current network". Predicted safe address = 0x4f89A94d00330d9eB12236eB5442F2FA15CCd566

Can you try setting isL1SafeSingleton to false?

L2 works fine on Chiado (as I mentioned in the question).
